# jQuery Mobile: Trying to get an icon to display in the middle of some text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get the icon to display in the middle of the words 'some text'.

Could anyone advise?

http://jsfiddle.net/LZxxB/50/

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">some</div>
<span class='ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-arrow-u-l' style="display:inline-block;"></span>

    <div style="display:inline-block;">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw your css, can you try getting rid of top and left 50%?

Comment: That seems like it will do the trick, but as I have no control over the framework's css, how to override it inline?

Comment: Yea, I think over-riding it inline can do the trick, if you can try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. You basically make an icon button that is not a button.

The HTML:

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">some</div>
    <span class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon nonbuttonicon" >
        <span class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline"></span>
    </span>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">text</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.nonbuttonicon .ui-btn {
    background: transparent;
    cursor: default;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nonbuttonicon .ui-btn:hover{
    background: inherit;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LZxxB/53/)**

**UPDATE:**

Here is a way without using jQM buttons and a single span:

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">some</div>   
    <span class="ui-alt-icon ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>    
    <div style="display:inline-block;">text</div>
</div>

.inlineIcon  {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.inlineIcon:after{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LZxxB/58/)**

An if you like the white icon on top of the round disk, the CSS becomes even simpler:

```
<span class="ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>

.inlineIcon  {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LZxxB/60/)**

Comment: Nice! But i'd like to avoid the extra markup/css needed to workaround it being a button

Comment: No problem, see my updated answer using single SPAN and no btn CSS

Comment: Nice! If you want a white icon, simply remove ui-alt-icon from the span.

Answer (score 2):

These lines of code will reset the jquery mobile css that is displaying it differently. You might need to tweak it a little bit to fit your needs.

```
div span.ui-icon-arrow-u-l:after {position:relative;}
div span.ui-icon-arrow-u-l {display:inline-block;height:30px;margin-top:0;width:16px;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Getting close. Does the 6px need hardcoding? What if I set my font size to more than 1em. Will it break it?